# File Being Used By Two Processes

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, process, io

I'm trying to write some code that deletes an image off the hard-disk once the user clicks on some delete button. Sometimes I get the following exception and sometimes I do not. And when I actually do, if I try to delete it again, it does work most of the time.

This is the exception:

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it
>   is being used by another process.

I guess I should provide some details on what is happening exactly:

- User uploads an image, which is then displayed on the screen so the user can see what he/she has just uploaded.
- A delete button is shown to the user in case he/she decides that they do not really want to upload this image.
- When the user clicks the delete button, I call a method that  deletes the image and all of its previously created thumbs.
- Finally, the image is remove from the screen and the user can upload other images.

I'm not sure how I could solve this problem because the exception does not provide any information about which other process is holding onto the file. Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

```
    public byte[] ResizeImageToBytes(string path, int size, string name)
    {
        var newImage = Image.FromFile(path);
        int newWidth; int newHeight;
        if (size == 470)
        {
            if (newImage.Height != 250)
            {
                newWidth = (int)Math.Round(newImage.Width * (100 / (newImage.Height / 250)) * 0.01);
                newHeight = 250;
            }
            else
            {
                newWidth = newImage.Width;
                newHeight = newImage.Height;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (newImage.Width > newImage.Height)
            {
                newWidth = size;
                newHeight = newImage.Height*size/newImage.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                newWidth = newImage.Width*size/newImage.Height;
                newHeight = size;
            }
        }

        var thumb = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(thumb);
        gfx.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        gfx.DrawImage(newImage, rect);
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        thumb.Save(ms, newImage.RawFormat);
        return ms.GetBuffer();
    }

    public void SaveImage(byte[] toSave, string path)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ms.Write(toSave, 0, toSave.Length);
            using(var theImage = Image.FromStream(ms)) 
            {
                theImage.Save(path);
            }
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        var newFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["Filedata"];
        string guid = Guid.NewGuid() + newFile.FileName;
        string itemImagesFolder = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/ItemImages/"));
        string fileName = itemImagesFolder + "originals/" + guid;
        newFile.SaveAs(fileName);

        string finalPath;
        foreach (var dim in ImageDimensionsList.Options)
        {
            var bytes = _imageService.ResizeImageToBytes(fileName, dim.Width, guid);
            finalPath = itemImagesFolder + dim.Title + "/" + guid;
            _imageService.SaveImage(bytes, finalPath);
        }
        return Content(guid);
    }
```

Comment: ASP.NET, I assume? If so, please retag the question.

Comment: It doesn't have to be another process. If YOU have a handle open on the file when you try to delete it, the delete will still fail with that error.

Comment: Try to release the resources that are using the image in your program...making use of 'using' statement would help!
Or load new image each time u access it!

Comment: Show the code you are using to write to the file and to read from it.

Comment: ok I'll update my source code to show the methods that resize and save the image.

Comment: Just use `using` in `ResizeImageToBytes` method same way you're using it already in `SaveImage`.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: What objects do you suggest I should be wrapping with a using statement?

Comment: `newImage` and `thumb` as they both have their own `Dispose` method.

Comment: Yeah, Darin put code to the words - glad you got it solved. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't disposing any of the disposable resources you are working with in your `ResizeImageToBytes` method. This leaves leaking handles in your application and of course locked files. Try this:

```
public byte[] ResizeImageToBytes(string path, int size, string name)
{
    using (var newImage = Image.FromFile(path))
    {
        int newWidth; int newHeight;
        if (size == 470)
        {
            if (newImage.Height != 250)
            {
                newWidth = (int)Math.Round(newImage.Width * (100 / (newImage.Height / 250)) * 0.01);
                newHeight = 250;
            }
            else
            {
                newWidth = newImage.Width;
                newHeight = newImage.Height;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (newImage.Width > newImage.Height)
            {
                newWidth = size;
                newHeight = newImage.Height * size / newImage.Width;
            }
            else
            {
                newWidth = newImage.Width * size / newImage.Height;
                newHeight = size;
            }
        }

        using (var thumb = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight))
        using (var gfx = Graphics.FromImage(thumb))
        {
            gfx.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            gfx.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            gfx.DrawImage(newImage, rect);
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                thumb.Save(ms, newImage.RawFormat);
                return ms.GetBuffer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As far as your `SaveImage` method is concerned, well, this method seems redundant to me as it already exists in the .NET framework. It's called [File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx):

```
public void SaveImage(byte[] toSave, string path)
{
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, toSave);
}
```

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I did and I've just tried it a few times and I did not get any exceptions :)

Answer (score 0):

During the upload routine, are you using the `using` statement around your file reader? if no, then the file resource is not returned to the OS thus, it is still being "used".

Comment: Actually yes I do have a using statement. But there are more than one method that are involved, including the one that resizes the image. But I assume if that method is still holding onto the resources, then the `SaveImage` method should be the one complaining in the first place?

Comment: @Kassem: now that you've retag your question, i have no experience in asp.net, but i see many locations in your code that are not using the `using` statement. try wrapping all file handlers by `using`.

Answer (score 0):

To find information about what other process is holding onto the file, you should use a tool like ProcessExplorer (sysinternals.com).  It has this handy search feature (Find > Find Handle or DLL) where you enter a string like the filename and it will search all handles and tell you which process has the handle open.

Often when I run into an unexpected error like yours,  this is the first place I go.

Hope this helps,

John